# Coveo Cloud Not Recording Click Through Event in Analytics

Tags: coveo

We are not seeing click events registering in the Coveo Cloud analytics.  Anyone know what we might be missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common issue when removing the CoveoResultLink class from your Result Templates. Here is a Knowledge base article on this issue:

[developers.coveo.com/display/SupportKB/No+Clicks+in+Coveo+Usage+Analytics](https://developers.coveo.com/x/_oX2AQ)

Coveo JavaScript Framework attach to this HTML Class in order to send the click events. If this class is removed, click events will no longer be registered. Adding multiple classes on a DOM object is not a problem in HTML5, so I would recommend to add your own class if you need to customize the style, but do not remove that base class.